# How to check if DateTime object was not assigned?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime

So, First of all. Code: 
I've got a class:

```
public class Myobject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is part of very simple source:

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject();
mo.Code= "sth";
// NO action on StartDate property! 

    if (mo.StartDate.HasValue)
    {
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inStartDate", mo.StartDate.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        sc.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inStartDate", DBNull.Value));
    }
```

Simple 'if' - Sql Server 2008, throw an error - when gets null Datetime (it has to be DBNull.Value)
So I want to check it first, and then pass right value or DBNull.

My problem is - this 'if' always retruns true! Why!?

Also tried that:

```
if (mo.StartDate.Value == null)
```

but it always returns false. How come it is not a null? It was not even created..

So.. **How to check if DateTime object was not assigned?**

Comment: Cannot reproduce that condition with the snippet provided. Is there more to the story?

Comment: Is there anything else in MyObject we should know about (constructor, etc)?

Comment: Agreed, can't reproduce.  I'm thinking there must be somewhere the DateTime is getting set unbeknownst to you...?

Comment: HasValue is the right way to check if a Nullable<> is not assigned. I think there might be another problem, have you checked the mo.StartDate.Value in the debugger (with a breakpoint in the first sc.Parameters.Add line)?

Comment: Try to check if `mo.StartDate.Value <> DateTime.MinValue`. Is it really a Nullable DateTime?

Comment: "Simple 'if' - Sql Server 2008, throw an error" - **what** error message is given?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (mo.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault() != DateTime.MinValue) 
{
  // True - mo.StartDate has value
}
else
{
  // False - mo.StartDate doesn't have value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

should just be able to do

```
mo.StartDate != null
```

instead of

```
mo.StartDate.Value != null
```

Comment: I don't think that's his main issue though, we've shown his code should work, there must be something behind the scenes that is setting his property.

Comment: I was trying to show a solution to the second part where mo.StartDate.Value == null was always returning false, i wrote the wrong thing for the second part i've edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Running the simplest test with that class (as you presented it) yields false:

```
        var mo = new Myobject();

        Console.WriteLine(mo.StartDate.HasValue);
```

Output is False.

I'd put a breakpoint on your constructor (if you have one), make sure nothing else is getting assigned, and walk through any methods called along the way to make sure there's nothing else setting the property that may not be immediately obvious...

Can you post more code, perhaps?  There must be something in code not posted setting the property.

Comment: In 5min, one more test I have to do

Comment: Well, it starts in another application. It is only test project, so names are very temporary. 
I created, just like the example - my object. And assign ONLY "code", than I pass this object via WCF, to WCF host - Windows Service. 

I never change this object, only pass to another functions, and in the end I want to insert properties of that object to Database. Very simple. To do that - i use stored procedures and ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're checking for null is fine, there must be something else that's setting the field's value.

---

To find what's setting the field you could right-click it then do find all references, then scan the list for any assignments.

Failing that, you could change it to an explicitly defined property temporarily and set a breakpoint within the set method, then execution will pause whenever the value is set and you can look up the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

`.HasValue` and `==null` are the ways to check whether `DateTime?` is assigned a value or not. You are doing it right. There might be problem somewhere else that `.HasValue` returns true always.