# If a DateTime object cannot be null, what is it before it is assigned?

Tags: c#

If a DateTime instance has not been assigned yet, what is it's value?

To look at a specific example: In the class below, would "UnassignedDateTime==null" return true?

And if so, surely it is massively illogical that such a reference could be null, but not assigned null?

```
class TestClass
{
    public DateTime AssignedDateTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime UnassignedDateTime {get; set;}

    public TestClass()
    {
        AssignedDateTime=DateTime.Now;
        //Not assigning other property
    }

}
```

I've already checked this answer to a similar question, but it's about DateTime? which is nullable.. [How to check if DateTime object was not assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584533/how-to-check-if-datetime-object-was-not-assigned)

Comment: Also should note that DateTime is not nullable. `DateTime d = null;` will not compile

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It will be `default(DateTime)` which by a design-decision happens to be `DateTime.MinValue`

`default(T)` is what types are initialized to when used as fields or array members.
`default(int) == 0`,  `default(bool) == false` etc.
The default for all reference types is of course `null`.

It is legal to write `int i = default(int);` but that's just a bit silly. In a generic method however, `T x = default(T);` can be very useful.

> surely it is massively illogical that such a reference could be null, but not assigned null?

DateTime is a Value-type, (`struct DateTime { ... }`) so it cannot be `null`. Comparing it to null will always return false.

So if you want find out the assigned status you can compare it with `default(DateTime)` which is probably not a valid date in your domain. Otherwise you will have to use the nullable type `DateTime?`.

Comment: May want to add that `default(SomeClass)` will give you the default value of any type.

Comment: @Henk: If DateTime's default is not null does that mean it is not a reference type? If so, what type of type is it?

Comment: @Rick, Yes, @Davy is right. Easy to find, select it and hit F12. It is defined as a `struct`.

Comment: @Henk: +1 for mentioning DateTime is struct.

Answer (score 5):

A DateTime variable is by default `DateTime.MinValue` if you did not assign it another value http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It will probably hold the value of `DateTime.MinValue` (The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.)

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` will be at it's minimum value if it's initalized, but not set. e.g. `12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001`

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is `MinValue`, which I think is what it is initially. Because is it stored as an integer internally, that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Can't check right now but I think it defaults to: 01/01/0001 00:00:00.

If you debugged your code and hovered over the property it should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DateTime` is a struct it is not nullable (`DateTime?`), the condition `UnassignedDateTime == null` is always false.